# Prevent inline JavaScript on Internet Explorer 11 using Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, xss, content-security-policy

Is it possible prevent inline JavaScript on Internet Explorer 11 using CSP on ASP.NET WebForm? I know IE 11 does not support Content Security Policy Level 2 but it seen that support Level 1.0. I tried many way and there is not a clear answer out there. I tried:

- Response.AddHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'none'");
- Response.AddHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self'");
- Response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'self'");

it's not working.

Thanks!
Albert Torres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=content%20security) - IE 11 only has partial support.

> Partial support in Internet Explorer 10-11 refers to the browser only
>   supporting the `sandbox` directive by using the
>   `X-Content-Security-Policy` header

However, you could try this `sandbox` directive. [Description here](https://content-security-policy.com/):

> Enables a sandbox for the requested resource similar to the iframe
>   sandbox attribute. The sandbox applies a same origin policy, prevents
>   popups, plugins and script execution is blocked. You can keep the
>   sandbox value empty to keep all restrictions in place

e.g.

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: sandbox
```

Comment: Yes sandbox works but block all scripts and I was looking to only block inline script. so I guess the answer is Internet Explorer 11 can not block inline script using Content Security Policy right?

Comment: No, you don't get any granular control. `allow-scripts` is optional, however it will allow all scripts.