# How can I prevent XSS attack in Asp.net Webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, xss

How can I prevent XSS attack in `WebMethod` web service in `Asp.net web forms` ?
I set `ValidateRequest="true"`in webconfig but it doesn't work .

web.config :

```
<system.web>
 <pages  validateRequest="true"  />
</system.web>
```

page.aspx.cs :

```
  [WebMethod]        
    public static string New(string txtName){
              ....
     }
```

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran That's a defence against CSRF, not XSS

Comment: @getsetcode `validateRequest` is not a protection against csrf, but xss. However, it is by far not enough, and the question is too broad unfortunately. There are too many ways to exploit (and protect against) xss.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I know, I was replying to a comment which has since been deleted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do at least two things:

- Clean HTML fragments and documents from constructs that can lead to XSS attacks using [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) library.
- Start using [content security policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704605/prevent-inline-javascript-on-internet-explorer-11-using-content-security-policy) headers to prevent inline execution of the possible injected scripts.